# Issue with commas in the column while exporting SQL Server query result to .csv file with double quotes the data is splitting up to next columns

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have an issue with commas in the column while exporting SQL Server query results to a `.csv` file. The data is splitting up to next columns with double quotes, using SSIS.

This is my sample data:

```
EmpId    Location    Dept
---------------------------
 101     Nyc,AUS     It,HR
 102     Nyc,AUS     It,HR
```

When exporting this data into a `.csv` using SSIS, the data is splitting next column though I used text-qualifier double quote (").

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Not able to replicate. It is working as expected for me. Can you add some screenshots of `Flat File Connection Manager editor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use another column delimiter, such as ";" instead of "," when exporting it to .csv
When using text qualifier you have to make sure they are applied on the export also.
Open your .csv by notepad++ or any text editor and see if each Location-entry is surrounded by double quotes (")

Comment: Thank You for suggestion but  my requirement is  the column delimiter  ",". I am trying to workout in that approach